# Mapping types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible in TS  to transform this type

```
type input = {
    a: 1;
    b: 2;
    c: 3;
};
```

into this type

```
type output = { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } | { c: 3 };
```

?

Comment: You have several answers which have interpreted this as a way to transform a *value* of the `Input` type to a value of the `Output` type.  I believe you are instead asking how to generate the `Output` type itself given the `Input` type definition.  Either way, please [edit] the question to clarify what you want, so you get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: This question doesn't have any obvious relationship with reactjs (or even JavaScript, for that matter).  Could you remove any unrelated tags or clarify the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a type function that converts `Input` to `Output`; let's call it "`Split<T>`", for want of a better name.  Here's one approach:

```
type Split<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: Pick<T, K> }[keyof T];
```

On the inside we're using [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to represent the same type as `T` but only with the keys from `K`.  So `Pick<Input, "a">` is `{a: 1}`:

```
type Test = Pick<Input, "a">
// type Test = { a: 1; }
```

On the outside is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is what you get when you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some set of keys and then immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into it with the same set of keys.  I

Distributive object types let you take a type function `F<K>` for some keylike type `K`, and produce the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `F<K>` for each union member `K` in some set of keys.  In the above case, `keyof T` is the set of keys.  So the above will compute the union of `Pick<T, K>` for each `K` in `keyof T`, which is what you want:

```
type Input = {
  a: 1;
  b: 2;
  c: 3;
};

type Output = Split<Input>;
// type Output = Pick<Input, "a"> | Pick<Input, "b"> | Pick<Input, "c">
```

If you don't like seeing `Pick` in the IntelliSense output, you can inline the [definition of `Pick<T, K>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b24b6a1125321fb62d53dd544a6c59f03a6eac07/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1492-L1494) into `Split<T>`:

```
type Split<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in K]: T[P] } }[keyof T];

type Output = Split<Input>;
// type Output = { a: 1; } | { b: 2; } | { c: 3; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFKBDALigEYBuHKAIyICZzcBjIgZnIF9ytRIoBlMADYBLYAB4AKlAgAPYBDgATAM5QA9pQBWEBsAB8aChigBtANJQhcKAGsIIVQDMo4gLoBaAPxEACkIbWJABooU302Y1t7J1dObmhxCCUUdF9-UXgkYGCAIjxs3SwAekKoOOdE5Mx8IjIoNiwucGh+YWAaCSlZeWU1TW09A1wjMwsrSMdndy8q429RkJcicVmXOrqIuwmYhrKAeWRMtD5BEXSEZF1yYtKmqH3gQ5S-AIzkHLz9AB8oVJfzrKg2Uo+Sg31+Z0yOQY+SKJT2B2QRyMhBIpDW3yM1CgdHRVSYUFYdQaWCAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
type input = {
a: 1;
b: 2;
c: 3;
};

type output = { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } | { c: 3 };

let i : input = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

let o : output;

let {a, b, c} = i;

o = {a} || {b} || {c};
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have no idea how to implement this from scratch. But here's a library that does exactly this and much more (ts-toolbelt):

```
import { Object } from 'ts-toolbelt';

type Input = {
  a: 1;
  b: 2;
  c: 3;
};

type Output = Object.Either<Input, keyof Input>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this scales to more complicated `input` types, might get weird with nested things

```
type input = {
    a: 1;
    b: 2;
    c: 3;
};

// given key K, construct {[K]: T[K]}
type m2<T, K extends keyof T> = {[k in K]: T[k]}

// for each key K in T, construct {[K]: T[K]}, and union the results
type m1<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends any ? m2<T, K> : never;

type map<T> = m1<T, keyof T>;
type result = map<input>

declare const result : result;
if ("a" in result) {
    result.a // type 1
}
else if ("b" in result) {
    result.b; // type 2
}
else {
    result.c // type 3
}
```

Comment: Your `m2` is just [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).  Also note that TS naming conventions would have nonprimitive types be UpperPascalCase (so `M2<T, K>`, `Result`, etc) and type parameters are not lowercase (so not `[k in K]` but something like `[P in K]` instead)

Comment: I didn't realize that about M2. Neat!